# Ubuntu 16.04 freezing when streaming videos

Tags: 16.04, firefox, freeze, streaming

I am having a problem in pinpointing this issue, but here is the info:

Every once in a while, after some time, when I am watching streaming videos (Youtube, Udemy, Teachable, etc.) my laptop would freeze (as in it freezes and the audio keeps repeating the last 1 second). This also happened once when I had spotify open, but I think it was youtube, since I wasn't playing anything on spotify( that has been installed as snap, btw).

When this freeze happens, no matter how much time I wait, try to go for another TTY, nothing works, and I have to "Hard Reset" the machine.

I checked `dmesg` after reboot, see if I can find anything that helps, but didn't find anything (I am not sure what I am looking for).

I looked around to see if this would be a Firefox problem (latest version from ubuntu's repository), but couldn't find any similar problem.

For the record, this is my system info:

```
System: Ubuntu 16.04 x64 LTS with Gnome Shell v3.18.5
CPU: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2820  @ 2.13GHz
RAM: 4GB DDR3
Kernel: 4.4.0-119-generic
```

The laptop is not overheating, and this doesn't happen when I am listening to music/playing local videos, so I guess it is related to Firefox/wireless card.

Any help in pinpointing this issue will be appreciated. Also, if there's need of any additional info, please let me know.

P.S.: I know there will be the new ubuntu version (18.04) soon, but I really want to know why this is happening, so I don't make the same mistake.

Comment: I did not find that at first, but I don't think that it is the problem. I will give it a shot though. Thanks, and sorry if this is duplicated.

Comment: Hey, there are lots of reasons why the system might freeze and the c-state bug is not all that widely known. It's not a problem to post a question that turns out to be a duplicate anyway. Your processor is one of the Bay Trail ones, but still, please do let us know if that post actually helps you

Comment: I was testing it, so far I've been running streaming videos for about 4 hours, and it did not freeze, so I guess that was the problem. Thanks for the link to the solution.